# How to trigger a node using email regex in Watson Conversation?

Tags: json, regex, watson-assistant

I am trying to extract an email address from user input text in Watson Conversation. First thing first, I need to trigger a particular node using an if condition like this:

```
input.text.contains('\^(([^<>()[].,;:s@\"]+(.[^<>()[].,;:s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[‌​0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}‌​.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,‌​3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+‌​.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$\')
```

But it doesn't work, I tried a lot of regexes that I found on the internet but none of them work. Does anyone know how to write a proper regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a much simpler, *approximate*, regex to match emails that you need to use with [`String.matches(string regexp)`](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-methods.html#stringmatchesstring-regexp) method that accepts a regex:

```
input.text.matches('^\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+$')
```

Do not forget to double escape backslashes so as to define *literal* backslashes in the pattern.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\S+`  - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `@` - a `@` symbol
- `\\S+`  - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\\.`  - a literal dot
- `\\S+`  - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.